# How extract relations between Named entity?

Tags: information-extraction

I've used Opennlp to find named entities, now i'm searching for a technique to extract them and relations between two named etities using MEMM (maximum entropy markov models) .

Can anyone know how to proceed ?

(ps : excuse me for my bad english)

Thanks.

Comment: If your text has the named-entities identified, you can use a bootstrapping approach to extract relationships. For instance, ["Snowball: Extracting Relations from Large Plain-Text Collections"](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~gravano/Papers/2000/dl00.pdf), [implementation](https://github.com/davidsbatista/Snowball)

Improvements over the original algorithm ["Semi-Supervised Bootstrapping of Relationship Extractors with Distributional Semantics"](http://davidsbatista.github.io/publications/breds-emnlp_15.pdf), [implementation](https://github.com/davidsbatista/BREDS)